# how do i upload a file over ftp server from User interface?

Tags: java, jsp, ftp, apache-commons-net

I want to upload a file from user interface over ftp server. i know the procedure for uploading a file in java but i am predefined the file path in code but i want to upload a file from manually (User interface) how can i done using java and java servelet pages? any suggestions?

below is my java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    boolean result;
    try {
        client.connect("localhost");
        result = client.login("admin", "password");

        if (result == true) {
            System.out.println("Successfully logged in!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Login Fail!");
            return;
        }
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\uploadexample.txt");
        String testName = file.getName();
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        // Upload file to the ftp server
        result = client.storeFile(testName, fis);

        if (result == true) {
            System.out.println("File is uploaded successfully");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File uploading failed");
        }
        client.logout();
    } catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

jsp code :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
   <body>
    <h3>File Upload:</h3>
  Select a file to upload: <br />
   <form action="UploadServlet" method="post"
                enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
   <br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
   </form>
  </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Upload the file to the webserver, store it to a temporary file. Then upload it from web server to FTP server and finally delete the temporary file.

Comment: thanks for the reply,i want to upload file from UI using both java and jsp i need suggestions on that can u give any idea how to achieve that?

Comment: I thought I gave you such a suggestion. You have working Java code to upload a file to a FTP server. Then you only need to upload a file via JSP to the web server. On which part exactly do you have problems?

Comment: i am uploading a file now using file path in java,but i want to upload a file    from UI using jsp. how can i do that? please give any idea

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials out there covering that topic. Google is your friend. Try searching for keywords "jsp file upload tutorial".